# Beamer: Two columns with parallel text lined up?

Tags: two-column, parallel-texts

In Beamer I want a frame with text in two columns, with parallel content, like the following:

```
1 This is the first item in english        1 Este el primer item en español
2 Second english item                      2  Segundo item en español, pero 
                                              este es mas largo
3 Third very long item in                  3 Tercer item en español 
   English spanning
    spanning spanning
    many lines
4  ...                                      4 ...
```

like this, corresponding parts in the two text columns should be aligned on the same line. The best would be a solution which is not specific to beamer, as this should be a general problem.

Comment: Do you try to use `tabularx` environment?

Comment: Or perhaps `pdcolfparcolums` (a slight extension of the original `parcolumns` package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will extend my comment with illustration, if this is what you like to have:
[image]

This is obtained by:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{rXrX}
1   &   This is the first item in english        
        &   1   &   Este el primer item en español                    \\
2   &   Second english item                      
        &   2   &    Segundo item en español, pero este es mas largo  \\
3   &   Third very long item in English spanning spanning spanning many lines
        &   3   &   Tercer item en español                        \\
4   &   \dots
        &   4   &   \dots \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you not like to have numbers in the first in third row, just erase this columns. Also you can change the cell aligmnet with defining new column type `R`:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
```

which will smart align cell content to the left. For `\RaggedRight` you need to ad package `ragged2e` in preamble of your document. Some more place in table you can obtain, if to begin and end of parameters you add `@{}` like this:

```
{@{}rRrR@{}}
```

**Upgrade:**
The think over numbering of cells: since the cells in the same row have the same number, it would be enough to numbering rows only one time, for example only in the first column. This numbering can be automatized, and with this spare one care in typing this table.

Also use of package `booktabs` gives possibility to increase space between rows with adding `addlinespace` after each row (increasing of this space can be obtain also with for example `\\[1ex]`).

With this "improvements" the list of English/Español expression looks like:

[image]

As can you see, automatic numbering alloves also referencing of rows. Maybe this become handy. The code with described changes is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{booktabs}% <-- new
    \usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%%% new    
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newcounter{tabrowref}
\renewcommand\thetabrowref{\arabic{tabrowref}}
\newcommand{\getTabRowRef}{%
        \refstepcounter{tabrowref}
        \thetabrowref}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}>{%
    \color{black}%<-- for correct aligning of text in cells
    \getTabRowRef%<-- for automatic numbering of rows
    \setlength\hsize{0.05\hsize}}R%<-- for correct aligning of text in cells
    >{\color{blue}}R  %<-- colored text blue for English
    >{\color{orange}}R% and orange for English
                                >{\color{blue}}R  %<-- colored text blue for English
                                >{\color{orange}}R% and orange for English
                            @{}}
    &   This is the first item in English
        &       Este el primer item en Español                      
        \\  \addlinespace%<-- for increasing space between rows
    &   Second english item
        &        Segundo item en Español, pero este es mas largo    
        \\  \addlinespace
\label{row:3}   
    &   Third very long item in English spanning spanning spanning many lines
        &       Tercer item en Español \dots                        
        \\    \addlinespace
    &   \dots
        &       \dots 
    \end{tabularx}

\vskip 4em   
\textcolor{blue}{Automatic numbering of rows also enable to referencing a particular row. For example, considering row \ref{row:3} \dots}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @kjetibhalvorsen, see my upgraded answer. I slightly  change the layout of text appearance (now is colored). Actually, I'm curious, if any of given answers is what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This should be automatic:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,lmodern}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\arabic{mycounter}}

\newcommand{\LRenums}[2]{%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\mycounter] #1
\end{enumerate}
&
\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\mycounter] #2
\end{enumerate}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}XX@{}}
\LRenums{This is the first item in english}{Este el primer item en español} \\ 
\LRenums{Second english item}{Segundo item en español, pero este es mas largo} \\ 
\LRenums{Third very long item in English spanning spanning spanning many lines}{Tercer item en español} \\ 
\LRenums{\dots}{\dots} \\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]